# Alternative subequations numbering and references

Tags: math-mode, subequations

I know how to have a set of equations numbered as subequations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Some text here 
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:full}
    \begin{align}
        y_1 &= f_1(x) \label{eq:first} \\
        y_2 &= f_2(x) \label{eq:second} \\
        y_3 &= f_3(x) \label{eq:third}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\dots and now I can reference the full set as equations~(\ref{eq:full})
and for example the first as equation~(\ref{eq:first}). 

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Subequations as output]

Is it possible to have the equations labeled as in the following make-up:

[image: fake make up]

...and make the references to the single equations stay the same? (Or maybe change the "global" one to `1a--c`, not sure).

Comment: May be `empheq` can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to do it, but the name I gave to the environment should clear up my opinion about it. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\horriblesubequationsbox}
\NewEnviron{horriblesubequations}[1]{%
  \setbox\horriblesubequationsbox=\vbox{
    \hsize=\dimexpr\linewidth-8em\relax
    \begin{subequations}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \noindent\strut
    \begin{align}
    \BODY
    \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
  }%
  \begin{equation}\label{#1}
  \hspace*{4em}\left.\vcenter{\unvbox\horriblesubequationsbox\unskip}\right\rbrace
  \end{equation}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text here 
\begin{horriblesubequations}{eq:full}
  y_1 &= f_1(x) \label{eq:first} \\
  y_2 &= f_2(x) \label{eq:second} \\
  y_3 &= f_3(x) \label{eq:third}
\end{horriblesubequations}
\dots and now I can reference the full set as equations~(\ref{eq:full})
and for example the first as equation~(\ref{eq:first}). 

Some text here 
\begin{horriblesubequations}{eq:full+}
  y_1 &= f_1(x) \label{eq:first+} \\
  y_2 &= f_2(x) \label{eq:second+} \\
  y_3 &= f_3(x) \label{eq:third+} \\
  y_4 &= f_4(x) \label{eq:fourth+}
\end{horriblesubequations}
\dots and now I can reference the full set as equations~(\ref{eq:full+})
and for example the first as equation~(\ref{eq:first+}). 

\end{document}
```

Beware that, as the code stands, the global label is mandatory.

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1 and a very good candidate for the bounty ;-). I think that the rest of reference label tweaking (to obtain 1a, 1b, or similar) will be easily doable. An yes, not pretty, but basically for the brace that I can clearly get rid of --- in the end is very similar to a figure/subfigures thingy. Well, page breaking will be a bad thing...

Comment: @Rmano If you want “1a” and so on in the “inner” tags, just remove `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a manual way of setting the tags and specifying the references. It seems appropriate since there is a disconnect between what is labelled and referenced. Typically they're the same so there is no ambiguity to the reader, but in this case there is not (say) equation (1a).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}
\newcommand{\settag}[1]{
  \tag*{(#1)\qquad}
  \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation#1}}
\newcommand{\setmaintag}[1]{
  \tag*{(#1)\qquad\llap{(\theequation)}}
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
\newcommand{\setref}[1]{\edef\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text here 
\begin{align}
  \stepcounter{equation}
  y_1 &= f_1(x) \settag{a}\ltxlabel{eq:first} \\
  y_2 &= f_2(x) \setmaintag{b}\ltxlabel{eq:second}\setref{\theequation}\ltxlabel{eq:full} \\
  y_3 &= f_3(x) \settag{c}\ltxlabel{eq:third}
\end{align}
\dots and now I can reference the full set as equations~\eqref{eq:full}
and for example the first as equation~\eqref{eq:first}. 

\end{document}
```

`\ltxlabel` allows one to set the `\label` immediately, which is otherwise deferred until the `\tag` is set within an `align`.

No consideration for [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) was given, nor tested. The same goes for the "maybe" options in the question.

---

For an even number of equations, you can move the main equation up/down as needed:

[image]

```
Some text here 
\begin{align}
  \stepcounter{equation}
  y_1 &= f_1(x) \settag{a}\ltxlabel{eq:first} \\
  y_2 &= f_2(x) \setmaintag{b}\ltxlabel{eq:second}\setref{\theequation}\ltxlabel{eq:full} \\
  y_3 &= f_3(x) \settag{c}\ltxlabel{eq:third}
\end{align}
\dots and now I can reference the full set as equations~\eqref{eq:full}
and for example the first as equation~\eqref{eq:first}. 
\begin{align}
  \stepcounter{equation}
  y_1 &= f_1(x) \settag{a}\ltxlabel{eq:first2} \\
  y_1 &= f_2(x) \settag{b}\ltxlabel{eq:second2} \\
  y_2 &= f_3(x) \setmaintag[\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot]{c}\ltxlabel{eq:third2}
    \setref{\theequation}\ltxlabel{eq:full2} \\
  y_3 &= f_4(x) \settag{d}\ltxlabel{eq:fourth2}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Although this is nice (I do not understand the phrase where you say that there is no 1a, it seems to me that the referencing is working) I would prefer an automatically numbered thing.... and the positioning of the collective (1) become tricky in case of an even number of equations.... anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Rmano : How many of these sub-numberings do you have that warrants automaton?

Comment: @Rmano: You only have an equation marked `(a)` as part of a cluster marker `(1)`, so there's no explicit `(1a)` label. It would be similar to not adding the chapter mark to a section, and then referring to (say) section 3 in chapter 2 as section 3.2. It's just not that common.